# Managing the Scope of a TagHelper

Tags: asp.net-core, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Reading and learning about TagHelpers from a book so I wrote and used a TagHelper.
Writing it:

```
public class ButtonTagHelper: TagHelper
{
    public string BsButtonColor { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("class", $"btn btn-{BsButtonColor}");
    }
}
```

and then using it in Razor like this:

```
<button bs-button-color="danger" type="submit">ADD</button>
```

OK I learned that much. Now in the next section about scopes it is saying:
[image]

which confuses me and I don't understand it. WHY? In my code above I didn't say apply it to all buttons. Where did that get from? 
My understanding was that it looks at `bs-button-color` so if another button declaration in Razor doesn't have that, why would it be a problem?

Comment: It comes from `Button`TagHelper. It's the prefix.

Comment: @RicardoPeres sorry can you please explain a little more. I am still dumb

Comment: The class starts with Button, so, by default, it applies to all <button> elements. But you can change this, e.g., restrict the applicability. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-3.1.

Answer (score 0):

OK went back to start of the chapter and read it again. Here is the convention I had missed reading it in round one:

```
The NAME of the TagHelper combines the name of the element it transforms followed by the word TagHelper.
```

and in my example the class is called `ButtonTagHelper` so it means it wants to apply it to `BUTTONS`